# Asynchio coexisting with current code base

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a body of code that runs efficiently with one critical exception - a json API call.  My question relates to whether I can utilize asyncio / aiohttp in concert with my existing synchronous code, or whether it must be adapted as a complete framework.  A complexity in my case is that it sits within a Flask application, so any amendment to the structure will be that much more difficult.  In summary, I just want to make the json call asynchronous.

The function which makes the call can be simplified as follows:

```
def iterate_rankings():
    location_choices = get_locations() # dataframe with selected locations for download

    i = 0
    max_i = len(locations)
    while i < max_i:
        if locations.iloc[i, locations.columns.get_loc('select')] == 'Y':
            rankings = get_rankings(locations[['id', 'name']].iloc[[i]]) # simple API call
            df = get_games(rankings) # high volume API call
           
            df.to_csv(Config.CLASH_PATH + '/src_code/locations/data/' + name, index=False)
        i += 1
```

The high volume API call resides within my get_games() function:

```
def get_games(rankings):

    i = 0
    max_i = (len(rankings.index))
    ladder_cnt = 0
    while i < min(1000, max_i):
        player_tag = rankings.iloc[i, 0]

        with open(Config.CLASH_PATH + '/clashroyale.pem') as f:
            my_key = f.read().rstrip("\n")
            f.close()

        base_url = "https://api.clashroyale.com/v1"
        n_player_tag = player_tag.replace('#', '%23')
        endpoint = f'/players/{n_player_tag}/battlelog'

        request = urllib.request.Request(
             base_url+endpoint,
             None,
             {
                 "Authorization":  "Bearer %s" % my_key
             }
             )

        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read().decode("utf-8")
        data = json.loads(response)

        j = 0
        max_j = len(data)

        while j < max_j:
            game = data[j]

            if (game['type'] == 'PvP') and (((game['gameMode'])['name'] == 'Ladder_CrownRush') or \
                                            ((game['gameMode'])['name'] == 'Ladder_GoldRush') or \
                                            ((game['gameMode'])['name'] == 'Ladder_GemRush'
                                                                           '') or \
                                            (game['gameMode'])['name'] == 'Ladder'):

....
```

I left in the final part of the code since I am utilizing an additional json processing step.  I have noted in most of the asyncio / aiohttp examples a few differences I am struggling to work through:

1. most examples hit three or four sites randomly.  Here I am repeating the call to the same site.  Accordingly, I believe that I will likely require use of the limit semaphore since the volume of records will approach 1 million calls;
2. most of the examples quickly save the data to a file, as opposed to performing processing "in the moment".  I can amend my code to split the json parsing part out (and it seems that it would make sense to update to ujson for speed), and the order of the collected records is unimportant.  But how would I save the collected records into a memory resident dataframe (as opposed to saving to disk which just creates a later bottleneck)?  Most examples I am finding on YouTube, etc. tend to utilize aiofiles.  Is my design pattern faulty to keep memory resident?  My machine is stable and my work is hobby related, but losing 24 hours of downloads due to a crash is something that is worth greater consideration to preserve the vendor's resources.

As alternatives, I see there is also a "simple_requests" function - I am open to other options if they achieve my objective more simply.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: Ooops.  Just noted that I have a file read in my loop.  That's getting corrected.  I've also found an interesting link to use of the map function to use multiple threads for reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simplified approach using multithreading and map.  I also utilized the request library in place of my existing urllib code.  The solution is as follows:

```
from requests import Request
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def get_games(rankings):

    with open(Config.CLASH_PATH + '/clash.pem') as f:
        my_key = f.read().rstrip("\n")
        f.close()    base_url = "https://api.clashroyale.com/v1"
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer %s" %my_key}
    itm = list()
    itm.append(base_url)
    itm.append(headers)
    processed = 0

    def call_clash(call_var):
        base_url = call_var[0]
        headers = call_var[1]
        player_tag = call_var[2]
        n_player_tag = player_tag.replace('#', '%23')
        endpoint = f'/players/{n_player_tag}/battlelog'
        dat = requests.get((base_url + endpoint), headers=headers).json()
        return dat

    players = list()
    while i < min(1000, max_i):
        call_var = list()
        ind_rng = range(i, min((i+8), (max_i)), 1)
        itm_lst = (itm.copy())

        call_var = [itm_lst + [rankings.iloc[q, 0]] for q in ind_rng]
        #data = call_clash(itm_lst)
        pool = ThreadPool(len(call_var))
        results = pool.map(call_clash, call_var)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        for result in results:
            players.append(result)
        print(f'players retrieved: {i}')
        i += 8
```

Credit to the author of the article below:

https://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line